# How do I split a string by whole strings?

Tags: java

So, I am trying to split a string but I don't just want to split it by single character strings, but rather by entire strings.

So if my String is `["hello buddy my name is buddy"]`, my delimiter would be `"buddy"`.

I want it to split into: `["hello", "my name is"]`.

I hope i'm not over complicating it.

Comment: Should the split occur even if `buddy` is not the entire word?  For example, `"will you be my funbuddy today?"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    String test = "hello buddy my name is buddy";
    String[] res = test.split("buddy");
    for (String s: res) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Seems to do what you want, no?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you will be splitted based on user-supplied input, you'll want to pass it to `Pattern.quote()` first, e.g. `String[] res = test.split(Pattern.quote("buddy"));`